# Importing MGRS data to QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, distribution, mgrs

In QGI 3.16.5-Hannover on my MacOS 10.15.1, I have a CSV file with MGRS coordinates of the distribution of some species in a country. These are CGRS cell references for 50km cells (I already have the CGRS squares of the country).

I tried to vectorise the coordinates but I have only one field. I downloaded MGRS tools and I saw that I can convert each coordinate one by one but I would like to know if I can do it automatically because I have a lot of data.

Do you know if it is possible to transform them in R and then add them as a layer with the CGRS squares? I am very new to all of these.

Comment: You have tried "Add delimited text layer"? What do you mean by "I have only one field"

Comment: I hope it doesn't come across as condescending, but I just did a Google search for "MGRS batch converter" and the first hit looks exactly like what you want.

Comment: How many digits do the MGRS coords have? Can you post a few lines as an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your csv file into "my maps" on google maps, and then after that export the data into KML. Upload KML into QGIS.